# showing previous and current month data in table using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show three different figures of the same column In a mysql query, I would like to keep one month static: April, so it would be a case like this I want to show The current month, the previous month and the static month of the year I'm working with, in this case let us stick with 2012

```
Example
Tablename:payment

   id ,  pay_date,    amount
    1    2012-02-12    1000
    2    2012-03-11    780
    3    2012-04-15    890
    4    2012-05-12    1200
    5    2012-06-12    1890
    6    2012-07-12    1350
    7    2012-08-12    1450
```

So what I want to do is show the column `amount` for the month of April as I said I want to keep that row static: `890`, the current month lets say the current month is August:`1450` and the previous month amount which would be July:`1350`: so the final result would be something like this:

```
april_amount   current_month_amount  previous_month_amount
     890                 1450                 1350
```

However I'm stuck here:

```
select amount as april_amount
from payment
where monthname(pay_date) LIKE 'April'
and year(pay_date) LIKE 2012
```

I hope the question is written clear enough, and thanks alot for the help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the results can be rows instead of columns:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(pay_date), amount FROM payment

WHERE  pay_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01'
                    AND '2012-04-30'

    OR pay_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
                      - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 DAY
                    AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)

    OR pay_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
                      - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 DAY
                      - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
                    AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d791/1/0).

Comment: Is there no way I could get it in column

Comment: I'm Using columns because i'm not just working with one row of data but several, i just used the above table as a small example

Comment: @dames: Could you elaborate what the other rows contain?

Comment: For example a single month may have several entries so what I would also want is the sum of that particular month with the several enteries but to show the latest paydate I know it seems a bit unclear but I'm trying as best to make you understand example: if i have     '2012-02-12    5000,    2012-02-18    1000', I would want the query to produce a final result of    '2012-18-12    6000'

Comment: @dames: I'd still recommend having the months going down the rows and the values going across - are you after something like [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84fcc/1/0)?

Comment: Can I send you an excel document and you have a look at it which would give you an idea about what Im working with

Comment: @dames: Was that fiddle not what you wanted?  How about you edit your question to show the relevant snippet from the Excel file, so that all readers of this question can reach the same understanding?

Comment: The fiddle seems perfect but its a case where I am working with alot of names from several tables for each month, and I will try to extract the data from the excel file

Comment: The comment which stated how to get it into column is gone could you edit the sqlfiddle to adjust it to be in columns please

Comment: @dames: It's not easy to transpose such data in MySQL (one would need to use separate queries to obtain the last payment per month and the total payments per month, then combine them with `UNION`).  I *strongly* recommend that you use the query as given and perform any presentational transformations, such as transposition, in your application.

Comment: Yes I understand. Have a look at the fiddle I made a small edit to it, how would I sum the value for august

Comment: could you have a look at this question it may give more clarity please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161658/showing-one-column-several-times-with-data-from-3-different-date-intervals

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off here.  But try:

```
select top 1 
  p.amount, c.amount, n.amount 
from payment c
  inner join payment p ON p.pay_date < c.pay_date
  inner join payment n ON n.pay_date > c.pay_date
where monthname(c.paydate) LIKE 'April'
  and year(c.pay_date) LIKE 2012
order by p.pay_date DESC, n.pay_date ASC
```

EDIT, I didnt read your question properly.  I was going for previous, current, and next month. 1 minute and I'll try again.

```
select top 1 
  p.amount AS april_amount, c.amount AS current_month_amount, n.amount AS previous_month_amount
from payment c
  inner join payment p ON monthname(p.pay_date) = 'April' AND year(p.pay_date) = 2012
  inner join payment n ON n.pay_date > c.pay_date
where monthname(c.paydate) = monthname(curdate())
  and year(c.pay_date) = year(curdate())
order by n.pay_date ASC
```

This assumes there is only 1 entry per month.

Ok, so i haven't written in mysql for a while. here is what worked for your example data:

```
select
  p.amount AS april_amount, c.amount AS current_month_amount, n.amount AS previous_month_amount
from payment AS c
  inner join payment AS p ON monthname(p.pay_date) LIKE 'April' AND year(p.pay_date) LIKE 2012
  inner join payment AS n ON n.pay_date < c.pay_date
where monthname(c.pay_date) LIKE monthname(curdate())
  and year(c.pay_date) LIKE year(curdate())
order by n.pay_date DESC
limit 1
```

the previous month table joined is counterintuitively named `n`, but this works.  I verified it in a WAMP install.

To handle aggregates per month you can use subselects. Performance may suffer on very large tables (millions of rows or more).

```
SELECT SUM( a.amount ) AS april_amount, 
 (
  SELECT SUM( c.amount ) 
  FROM payment c
  WHERE MONTH( c.pay_date ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) )
 ) AS current_month_amount, 
 (
  SELECT SUM( p.amount ) 
  FROM payment p
  WHERE MONTH( p.pay_date ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 
  MONTH )
 ) AS previous_month_amount
FROM payment a
WHERE MONTHNAME( a.pay_date ) =  'April'
AND YEAR( a.pay_date ) =2012
```

Comment: what if its a case where there are several entries  per month and thanks a million so far, ill try it and let you know the outcome?

Comment: `previous_month_amount` would more accurately be named `previous_payment_amount`

Comment: @dames that last query is the one that actually works the way you wanted. I should probably erase the first two.

Comment: So what about the case when there are more than one enteries for the month because to be honest I will be working with several monthly records

Comment: I'll give you a less confusing query using sub-selects.

Comment: ok thanks also i don't mean to drift but look at this question instead its the same but i have two extra tables to include http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161658/showing-one-column-several-times-with-data-from-3-different-date-intervals

Comment: I've now answered 3 questions of yours and all you've done is change your question every time.