# showing one column several times with data from 3 different date intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to show three different figures of the same column In a mysql query and joining all three tables, I would like to keep one month static: April, so it would be a case like this I want to show The current month, the previous month and the static month of the year I'm working with, in this case let us stick with 2012

```
table: persons
ID     name
 1     Carl

table: vehicle  
ID     v_name         person_veh
100   Dodge Viper       1


Table:payment
 pay_id , pay_date,    amount  person_id
    1    2012-02-12    1000        1
    2    2012-03-11    780         1
    3    2012-04-15    890         1
    4    2012-05-12    1200        1
    5    2012-06-12    1890        1
    6    2012-07-12    1350        1
    7    2012-08-12    1450        1
```

So what I want to do is show the column amount for the month of April as I said I want to keep that row static: `890`, the current month lets say the current month is `August:1450` and the previous month amount which would be July:1350: so the final result would be something like this:

```
name     v_name    april_amount   current_month_amount  previous_month_amount
Carl   Dodge viper    890                 1450                 1350
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following - which uses an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select p.name,
  v.v_name,
  sum(case when Month(py.pay_date) = 4 then amount end) april_amount,
  sum(case when Month(py.pay_date) = Month(curdate())
        then amount end) current_month_amount,
  sum(case when Month(py.pay_date) = Month(curdate())-1
        then amount end) previous_month_amount
from persons p
left join vehicle v
  on p.id = v.person_veh
left join payment py
  on p.id = py.person_id
group by p.name,
  v.v_name
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97b8c/13)

Comment: Thank U so much. If only you knew how grateful I am

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT a.name, b.pay_date, b.amount, b.person_id, c.v_name 
FROM persons a
LEFT JOIN payment b on a.id = b.person_id 
LEFT JOIN vehicle c on a.id = c.person_veh
```

This query assumes id, person_veh and person_id are the like columns which links this user across these three tables